# C/C++: uint8_t bitfields behave incorrectly and inconsistently

Tags: c++

I have the following code:

```
struct Foo {
  uint16_t a:5;
  uint16_t b:5;
  uint16_t c:5;
};
uint16_t bits = 0xdae;
const Foo& foo = *reinterpret_cast<const Foo*>(&bits);

printf("%x %x %x\n", foo.a, foo.b, foo.c);
```

The output is what I expect when I work it out on paper:

> e d 3

If I use uint32_t instead of uint16_t bitfields, I get the same result.

But when I use uint8_t bitfields instead of uint16_t, I get an inconsistent result that is either:

> e d 6

or

> e d 16

Neither is correct. Why does using uint8_t for bitfields cause this strange behavior?

Comment: Pretty sure this is undefined behavior.

Comment: The `reinterpret_cast` is Undefined Behaviour, and also the layout of bit-fields is implementation defined you need to consult your compiler documentation.

Comment: With `uint16_t`, all three bitfields will fit in one 16-bit word. With `uint8_t`, it will break it up into three bytes.

Comment: Aside from the combination of implementation-specific and undefined behavior here, there's really no point in using fixed-size types as type specifiers for bitfields. After all, the point of a bitfield is to precisely specify the size of the field.

Comment: @FredLarson -- that's one possible layout, but this is all implementation-specific.

Comment: @PeteBecker: Granted. But I believe that's what's happening here.

Comment: What is this C/C++ you mention in the title?

Answer (score 5):

The compiler may add padding between structure members (or it may not, at its discretion) and you don't account for that when you just try to access the entire struct as a bunch of bits. Basically you can't just do that (the behaviour is undefined and your code is simply buggy). You need to access the structure members by name *or* use compiler specific extensions to control the layout/padding.

Comment: not with [bitfields it can't](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/bit_field)

Comment: @Mgetz the fact that the compiler *may* or *may not* pack adjacent bit field members at its discretion amounts to the same effect in practice as padding vs no padding.

Comment: @Mgetz -- the layout of structs that contain bitfields is implementation-specific, as the page you link to clearly says.

Comment: Maybe not in a bitfield, but between multiple bitfields all bets are off. 15 bits of bitfield cannot fit inside a single `uint8_t`, so something's got to give

Comment: @user4581301 the extra bits are automatically padding, and ensures the next member can be no closer than the padded area. Personally I avoid bit fields because they cause more problems than they are worth.

Comment: No closer does not also mean no further.

Comment: @PeteBecker I'd forgotten that, I can't edit my comment now but I'll leave it for the link which is useful

Comment: @Jesper Juhl: maybe it's worth noting that there are standardised way of controlling padding (not only compiler specific extensions)

Comment: @Stephan Lechner Good point. Like http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/types/aligned_storage & http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/memory/align I assume you mean. ?

Comment: @Jesper Juhl: actually I meant unnamed bitfield members of size 0, but explicit alignment as you mentioned is a good point, too.

Comment: @Stephan Lechner I had forgotten about that. Thanks. Have an upvote for your answer :-)

Answer (score 3):

The memory layout of bit-fields is implementation defined. Confer, for example, this [online draft c++ standard](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/papers/2013/n3690.pdf):

> 9.6 Bit-fields
>
> (1) ... Allocation of bit-fields within a class object is
>   implementation-defined. Alignment of bit-fields is
>   implementation-defined.

Thus, as you do not introduce explicit padding by bit-fields of length 0, you have no control on how the compiler will lay out your struct in memory. Actually, I think that you yield undefined behaviour, as you are converting one pointer to another one with probably different alignment requirements, and accessing padding bits (as it would happen with the assignment of a reinterpreted cast) is undefined behaviour, too.

Note that you can control padding of bit fields in a standardised way:

> (2) A declaration for a bit-field that omits the identifier declares an
>   unnamed bit-field. Unnamed bit-fields are not members and cannot be
>   initialized. [Note: An unnamed bit-field is useful for padding to
>   conform to externally-imposed layouts. — end note ] As a special case,
>   an unnamed bit-field with a width of zero specifies alignment of the
>   next bit-field at an allocation unit boundary. Only when declaring an
>   unnamed bit-field may the value of the constant-expression be equal to
>   zero.

See the following code that makes use of this feature; Note that it yields a different result as I found no way of how to control padding such that I could get consecutive 5-bit-piecies. So I adapted the example to something that works on the level of byte borders:

```
struct Foo {
    uint8_t a:5;
    uint8_t :0;
    uint8_t b:5;
    uint8_t :0;
    uint8_t c:5;
};

union DifferentView {
    uint32_t bits;
    struct Foo foo;
};

int main()
{
    union DifferentView myView;

    myView.bits = 0x0d0a0e;
    printf("%x %x %x\n", myView.foo.a, myView.foo.b, myView.foo.c);
    // Output: e a d

    return 0;
}
```